# Algorithm(Not sql) to get friend who has most mutual friends with a user

Tags: algorithm

Assume I have a table:

```
User | friend
_____________
 A   |  e

 e   |  A

 A   |  b

 A   |  c
```

**Input : Any user u1**

**Output: The user who has most mutual friend with u1.**

Is there any solution with **O(N)**? If not, please share your solutions, please.

**Feel free to share your map-reduce thoughts on this one**

Comment: `O(N)` what? Time? Space?

Comment: in here `N` denotes the number of people or number of entries? Also, is pre-processing allowed? (it seems the table is static and only the query is changing, is it indeed thecase?)

Comment: How about having a graph to store the data? Also having a hash map to store the indices of every vertex in the adjacency list, can make the algo run in ´O(1)` time.

Comment: A simple pre-processing (O(n) memory) will give O(1) - since there are only O(n) possible queries the answer to each can be stored in memory. For this reason, as well as the dynamism of social network, I don't think the OP meant to allow pre-processing.

Comment: what is mutual friend here ?

Comment: C is a mutual friend of A and B iff the entries:
(A, C), (B, C)
exist in the table

Comment: @AlmaDo O(n) is for time complexity.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie Graph is ok. How do you use graph to get the one who has most mutual friend with a user like u1? I don't think O(1) is workable.

Comment: @ChrisSu if you have an adjacency list (which stores all the neighbours) and a map which is `pair(vertex, index of vertex's neighbours in the adjacency list)` so having already your vertex you get the index in `O(1)` and then just go with `adjacencyList[index].size()`

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie Your solution can't guarantee the output is the friend with high number of "mutual friend." Example: (a,b) (a,c)(b,d)(b.e)(b,f)(c,g)(c,h). With your solution, the output should be b, But the correct output should be d,e,f,g,h. What's wrose, I don't think this solution is O(1) I think it's O(n^2) because you have to iterate friend of vertex for o(N) and for each neighbor you will have another n neighbors of that neighbor.